# vmware_vm_shell and powershell will not work

Tags: powershell, ansible

Hello I am having issues remotely signing SSL certs.
Background:
-Utilizing vmware vcenter -Ansible machine is linux -CA is Windows
script:

The script appears to run fine and change the host; however, when I log into the Certification Authority (DC) there is no srvr1.cer file. I can copy and fetch files from the same vm, but the powershell does not work.

I have tried the command prompt as well. The command works if run manually.

```
- name: sign csr
  vmware_vm_shell:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter server }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter pass }}"
    validate_certs: "no"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
    vm_id: "{{ vm name }}"
    vm_id_type: vm_name
    vm_username: admin
    vm_password: "{{ password }}"
    vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    vm_shell_args: 'certreq -config - -attrib "CertificateTemplate:My Template" C:\srvr1.csr C:\srvr1.cer
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Expected result:
srvr1.cer appears in C:\ on the domain controller.

Actual result:
Ansible returns a successful change, but no srvr1.cer file is present.

Comment: I have also attempted using the wait_for_process: true option; however, it hangs indefinitely.

Comment: any particular reason for using `local action` and `delegate_to` together.  and it should be `local_action`. delete the local_action and module keywords. Use directly the module name with the delegate_to: localhost option. Also re run the play in debug mode using -vvvv option. update the logs if the behavior is same

Comment: I was attempting anything I could to troubleshoot. I edited the syntax removing the superfluous wording. The behavior remains the same.